# OpenOffice Calc, function that supports regex-replace

Tags: regex, replace, openoffice-calc

I am very surprised today, not to find, in OpenOffice Calc, string function that supports my beloved PREG substitutions (Perl-Regular-Expressions).
Is there any other way to use these Reg replacements within a Calc function? Maybe another similar office? Maybe libre-office?
Version: OpenOffice 4.1.3
Language: german. 
BTW I do not recommend the German version to install. I will not do that anymore. Because the function names are all German.

Comment: i got a workaround, thats solves not really the problem, but at least alleviates my current problem (extract domain name from an emailaddress)

=MID(D4;SEARCH("@";D4;1)+1;99)

Comment: By the way, it's possible to install a localized version of OpenOffice, but set function names to english in settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some functions support simple regular expressions: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Calc#Regular_expressions_in_Calc_functions

For a complete regex spreadsheet function, create a general-purpose regex macro or add-in:
https://superuser.com/a/1072196/541756

When installing the German or other non-English version, always enable *Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> Formula -> Use English function names*.